# Bind Control to a User Control Property

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like my user control to modify the text of a `TextBlock` in its parent. The parent control should be able to bind the `TextBlock` to a property in the user control.

The `TextBlock` is currently not binding.

Here is how I am currently trying to do this:

**Parent Control:**

```
<localcontrols:MyControl TextName="{Binding texttest}"/>

<TextBlock x:Name="texttest"/>
```

**User Control Code:**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextNameProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TextName", typeof(TextBlock), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata((TextBlock)null, MyControl.TextNameValueChanged));

public TextBlock TextName
{
    get
    {
        return (TextBlock)this.GetValue(MyControl.TextNameProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(MyControl.TextNameProperty, value);
    }
}

private static void TextNameValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Do you have any binding errors when run in Output?

Comment: RelativeSource is probably necessary

Comment: @mvermef I can't see any errors in Output. Do you have any examples of RelativeSource?

Comment: This looks odd. Why don't you simply bind the TextBlock's Text property to a string property of your UserControl?

Comment: Actually thinking about it further that would be over kill and the posted answer is simplest and should work

Comment: Overkill? Not at all. Just change the type of your dependency property from TextBlock to string. You would thus be able to bind to other control types besides TextBlock, like TextBox, Label, etc.

Comment: How is your `DataContext` set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<localcontrols:MyControl TextName="{Binding ElementName=texttest}"/>
```